# How to reverse x-axis in box-plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, reverse, x-axis

People, please can you evaluate my code and give me a hand?

I need to reverse de X-axis of my box-plot, as you can see, the x-axis is the age in Ma, R plot the values in ascending range and I need them in the reverse form (ie 65-64, 64 -63, 63-62, 62-61, 61-60). I tried with scale_y_reverse (), but no good results

Please help me.

Thanks a lot.[Box-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRphz.png)

Install Tidiverse
`install.packages("tidyverse")`

Open library

`library(tidyverse)`

Usign qplot

`qplot(data =Filogen, x =    Filogen$EDAD_1, y = Filogen$AREA_SUR,   fill = Filogen$EDAD_1, geom =  "boxplot",   ylab = 'Área (km²)', xlab = 'Edad (Ma)')`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution is to use the `fct_rev()` function from the [forcats package](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_rev.html) (part of the tidyverse), for instance, using the example dataset from the [palmerpenguins package](https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/):

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

# Create a minimal reproducible example
MRE <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit()

# Plot the penguins data
qplot(data = MRE, x = species, y = bill_length_mm, fill = species, geom =  "boxplot", ylab = 'Área (km²)', xlab = 'Edad (Ma)')
```

[image: example_1.png]

And, using `fct_rev()`:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

# Create a minimal reproducible example
MRE <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit()

# Plot the penguins data
qplot(data = MRE, x = fct_rev(species), y = bill_length_mm, fill = species, geom =  "boxplot", ylab = 'Área (km²)', xlab = 'Edad (Ma)')
```

[image: example_2.png]

This solution relies on "species" being a factor. In your dataset, the equivalent variable is "EDAD_1". If "EDAD_1" is not a factor, before you plot the data, change it to a factor:

```
Filogen$EDAD_1 <- factor(Filogen$EDAD_1)
```

Comment: Mr jared

Thank you very much, I have had this problem for several days. You answered my question and I am very grateful to you.

Greetings

Comment: @jared - why did you answer this after voting to close as duplicate? dupes should just be closed, not answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I wrote an answer for it, then voted to close as duplicate, then posted the answer as I had already written it and thought it might be of use to OP - you are absolutely correct I should have looked for duplicates first and not wasted any time on it (sorry)